# How to sum one column from multiple

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Have table like :

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (a1 varchar(50),b1 money,c1 money,d1 money)

INSERT INTO @tbl (a1,b1,c1,d1)
values('test1',5,14.00,13.00),('test1',5,10.00,3.00),('test3',2,8.00,4.00)

a1       b1       c1    d1     
test1   5.00    10.00   3.00    
test1   5.00    14.00   13.00   
test3   2.00    8.00    4.00
```

Want sum d1 column and then need new column like sum_d1 column * 0.18, need something like :

```
select a1,b1,c1,d1,SUM(d1) as [d1_sum],[d1_sum] * 0.18 as [kpv],[d1_sum] + [kpv] as [new_sum]
from @tbl 
GROUP BY a1,b1,c1,d1
```

How to do it ?

**EDIT** :
response must be like :

```
 a1      b1       c1    d1     d1_sum   kpv  new_sum
test1   5.00    10.00   3.00    20.00   3.6    23.6
test1   5.00    14.00   13.00   20.00   3.6    23.6 
test3   2.00    8.00    4.00    20.00   3.6    23.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUM OVER()`

```
SELECT
    a1,
    b1,
    c1,
    d1,
    SUM(d1) OVER (PARTITION BY(SELECT NULL)) AS d1_sum,
    SUM(d1) OVER (PARTITION BY(SELECT NULL)) * 0.18 AS kpv,
    SUM(d1) OVER (PARTITION BY(SELECT NULL)) + (SUM(d1) OVER (PARTITION BY(SELECT NULL)) * 0.18) AS new_sum
FROM @tbl
```

or `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT
    t.a1, 
    t.b1, 
    t.c1, 
    t.d1,
    x.d1_sum,
    x.d1_sum * 0.18 AS kpv,
    (x.d1_sum * 0.18) + x.d1_sum AS new_sum
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(d1) as d1_sum FROM @tbl
) x
```

Comment: `SUM(d1) AS d1_sum` not work for me,I edit question , please check

Comment: thank you now it works perfect, Can you please explaint me `OVER (PARTITION BY(SELECT NULL))` this part , what are you doing here ?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx. The `PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)` just means that the `SUM` is applied to all rows.

Comment: Why not sum(d1) over () ?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, that's good too. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!